# Como agrupar dados de um outro agrupamento?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Possuo o seguinte dataframe:

```
x= {"Nome": ['Carla','Rafael','Juliana','Carla','Carla','Juliana','Rafael','Juliana','Rafael'],
    "Salario": [1200,1500,2000,1230,1250,2050,1700,2500,1750]}
tabela_salarios=pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Preciso calcular a porcentagem de variação entre os três de salario de forma que apareça da seguinte forma:

```
Nome  Variação Salário
Carla 1
Carla 1.25
Carla 1.016
```

E depois calcular essa porcentagem acumulada, que seria o produto de todas as variações:

```
Nome Porcentagem acumulada
Carla 1.27
```

Alguém sabe de que forma poderia fazer isso usando o groupby?

Comment: User123, boa tarde! Essa variação de 1.25 está correta?  A de 1.016 está correta? Abraço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução possível

```
df['Variação_Salario'] = df.sort_values('Nome').groupby(['Nome'])['Salario'].pct_change().fillna(0).add(1)
df['Porcentagem acumulada'] = df.sort_values('Nome').groupby(['Nome'])['Variaco_Salario'].cumprod()
df = df.sort_values('Nome')
```

1. Primeira linha agrupamos por nome e utilizamos `pct_change` do **pandas**
2. Segunda linha fazemos algo parecido com a primeira mas utilizamos o `cumprod`  do **pandas** para calcular o produto da variação
3. Ordenamos os valores para apresentar o data frame

**Saída:**

```
    Nome    Salario  Variaco_Salario    Porcentagem acumulada
0   Carla   1200        1.000000               1.000000
3   Carla   1230        1.025000               1.025000
4   Carla   1250        1.016260               1.041667
2   Juliana 2000        1.000000               1.000000
5   Juliana 2050        1.025000               1.025000
7   Juliana 2500        1.219512               1.250000
1   Rafael  1500        1.000000               1.000000
6   Rafael  1700        1.133333               1.133333
8   Rafael  1750        1.029412               1.166667
```

---

Uma outra possível solução:

Separei o código em 3 blocos pra resumir a explicação

1. Primeiro bloco ordena o data frame e estica(pivot) o data frame, transformando linha em coluna;
2. O segundo bloco cria a variação do salário e a porcentagem acumulada utilizando `pct_change()` e `cumprod()` do **pandas**
3. Cria novos data frames com os resultados

```
df['i'] = df.groupby('Nome')['Nome'].cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index(['i','Nome']).stack().unstack(1).reset_index(drop = True)

pct_change = df1.pct_change().fillna(0).add(1)

vsalario = pct_change.unstack().reset_index().drop(columns = 'level_1')
pa = pct_change.cumprod().unstack().reset_index().drop(columns = 'level_1')
```

**Saída:**

vsalario

```
    Nome    0
0   Carla   1.000000
1   Carla   1.025000
2   Carla   1.016260
3   Juliana 1.000000
4   Juliana 1.025000
5   Juliana 1.219512
6   Rafael  1.000000
7   Rafael  1.133333
8   Rafael  1.029412
```

pa

```
    Nome    0
0   Carla   1.000000
1   Carla   1.025000
2   Carla   1.041667
3   Juliana 1.000000
4   Juliana 1.025000
5   Juliana 1.250000
6   Rafael  1.000000
7   Rafael  1.133333
8   Rafael  1.166667
```